# Using Python to do SMTP Server with StartTLS

Tags: python, starttls, smtpd

I want to use Python to create an SMTP server that will use TLS via STARTTLS. The Python Lib/smtpd.py library doesn't seem to support this natively. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls

Comment: That's a client; I want to do an SMTP server.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Reading comprehension failure.

Comment: @vy32 I also want to implement a very simple smtp server, preferable with python. Did you ever succeed and may want to share your knowledge?

Comment: @soey I did not, but it seems that tintin below has done so.

Comment: @soey you know about [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) ?